# More than 1 flag per post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I've flagged a post as spam. Being forgetful, I clicked to flag it as spam again. Naturally I can't flag again, but, it appears as if I have flagged it twice, for different things.

[image]

Is this a bug? I never flagged it as offensive, abusive or hate speech.

Comment: spam/offensive has the same penalty and counted as the same

Comment: That still sounds like a bug to me :) It seems like there is a point system and because they have the same value, the site can't work out which to show I selected... Although, I guess it doesn't really matter :) Thanks for the answer @Sathya

Comment: well @Dave internally the flag is considered as a vote - so you're not too far on your observation of it being a point system

Comment: If a moderator flags a post as spam, it will be considered binding and will immediately reach the threshold of 6 to trigger a -100 rep penalty. The only difference is that Community, not the flagging moderator, will show up as the one who deleted it.

Answer (score 7):

The underlying system doesn't distinguish between spam and offensive.

We actually have it as `SpamOffensive`...

Comment: Wait, really? If that is the case, how are moderators and I able to see the difference in the queue and in the flag history respectively? Oh, and why doesn't a timestamp show up for such flags?

Comment: There *is* a technical difference. Spam flags feed into the spam filters, while offensive flags don't.

Comment: Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: Another moderator (as in community moderator) posted an answer here. Don't remember who, as I can't find the original answer.